# What does two return statements for javascript promise mean here?

Tags: node.js, jwt

i am learning javascript and Node.js and came across this code. I have a user.js representing user schema and server.js that contains my post route.

```
UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() {

  return user.save().then(()=> {  //Return Statement 2
    return token;                 //Return Statement 3
  });
};
```

I want to understand what two return statements mean when user.save() is called and in 'then' we return a token. Why do we need 'return' ahead of 'user.save()'

Here's the 'POST route'

```
user.save().then(()=>{
    return user.generateAuthToken();  //Return Statement 1
  }).then((token) =>{
    res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
  })
```

Why do we return 'user.generateAuthToken()' instead of just calling it ? Why are we using three return statements whereas according to my understanding no return statement is required as a promises automatically return something in the 'then' block.
Could someone please explain the flow here ? I would be very thankful to you.
Thanks.

Comment: The first `return` returns a token value for next `then` function call (note the parameter in 2nd `then`)

Answer (score 0):

You my friend are working with Promises..
(1st code)
when you call
    user.save()
you are returning a Promise..the function may or may not end successfully..Promises have a
    Promise.prototype.then
function..the first arg is a success function to be called when the function resolves(the real term)

In 2nd code..inside that 1st function you returned another Promise that's it(the whole then returns another Promise..but only if it resolves)

If you need to beat the crap out of JavaScript try googling Eloquent JavaScript (by Marijn Haverbecke)

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we need to 'return' ahead of 'user.save()'

This returns the promise that resolves the token. Without the return we'd have no way of accessing the token outside of the `save` function.

> Why do we return 'user.generateAuthToken()' instead of just calling it?

Again, we need the token. If we just call the function, the save is performed but we don't have the token when the promise resolves (in this case it's used for the header of the response).

> Why are we using three return statements whereas according to my understanding no return statement is required as a promises automatically return something in the 'then' block.

Your understanding is wrong. Whatever is returned from the promise is available to `then`, if nothing is returned, there is no parameter (in this case the token).

Answer (score 0):

In the first function, `user.save()` will return a promise, and as you are returning the token in the `then` block of `user.save()`, promise will resolve the value of token.

In the second function if you haven't used return ahead of `user.generateAuthToken();`, it will just execute that function and you will be getting the results of `user.save()` in the then block.

Comment: I am sorry if i am being naive here but seriously need to ask, what does **'promise will resolve the value of token'** means in layman language ?

Comment: The `Promise` object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value. Normally a Promise Object will have two methods` then` and `catch`. The callback function of `then` will be called on completion of the async operation. What I mean by Promise will resolve with a value is this `then`'s callback will be called on completion of async operation with an argument having that value.